# Schedule and Cancel List of Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom widget that must start a **list** of scheduled `Task` objects, for simplicity's sake, let's take Xamarin's Text-To-Speech example.

Now I'd like to schedule a speech, wait five seconds, then start another one. The only problem is that I don't know how to do this. Moreover, I must be able to cancel them all at once.

## Iteration 1: `Task.ContinueWith`

**EDIT**: based on suggestions, I am using `Task.ContinueWith` with a single cancelation token:

```
    public CancellationTokenSource cancel_source;
    public CancellationToken cancel_token;      

    public async void Play_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!is_playing)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("start");

            is_playing = true;

            cancel_source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cancel_token = cancel_source.Token;

            current_task =
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("first task");
                        await DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().SpeakAsync("Wait for five seconds...", cancel_source, cancel_token);
                    }
                ).ContinueWith(
                    async (arg) =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("wait task");
                        await Task.Delay(5000, cancel_token);
                    }
                ).ContinueWith(
                    async (arg) =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("last task");
                        await DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().SpeakAsync("You waited!", cancel_source, cancel_token);
                    }
                ).ContinueWith(
                    async (arg) =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("All done!");
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                    }
            );

            await current_task;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("stop");

            //foreach (var p in l)   <----------------- will bother about canceling next, not right now
            //{
            //    if (p.task.IsCompleted) continue;

            //    DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().CancelSpeak();
            //    p.source.Cancel();
            //}

            is_playing = false;

            //DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().CancelSpeak();
            //cancel_source.Cancel();
            //cancel_source = null;
            //current_task = null;
        }
    }
```

What I've implemented is weird, when I click the button, it just says "wait for 5 seconds", and it speaks the second part just when I click again.

My implementation is as follows:

```
public class TextToSpeechImplementation : ITextToSpeech
{
    public AVSpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer;
    public AVSpeechUtterance speechUtterance;
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsUtterance;
    public CancellationTokenSource cancel_source;
    public CancellationToken cancel_token;

    public async Task SpeakAsync(string text, CancellationTokenSource source, CancellationToken token)
    {
        cancel_source = source;
        cancel_token = token;

        tcsUtterance = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("START ASYNC IMPLEMENTATION {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        var now = System.DateTime.Now;

        speechSynthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();
        speechUtterance = new AVSpeechUtterance(text);

        speechSynthesizer.DidFinishSpeechUtterance += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("STOP ASYNC IMPLEMENTATION {0} duration {1}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"),
                                                                                                    (System.DateTime.Now - now).TotalSeconds);

        speechSynthesizer.DidCancelSpeechUtterance += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SPEECH CANCELED");

        speechSynthesizer.SpeakUtterance(speechUtterance);

        await tcsUtterance.Task;
    }

    public void CancelSpeak()
    {
        speechSynthesizer.StopSpeaking(AVSpeechBoundary.Immediate);
        tcsUtterance.TrySetResult(true);
        cancel_source.Cancel();
    }
}
```

I see the scheduled tasks are run almost simultaneously, so I get just "Wait for 5 seconds", and then nothing else (the tasks, apparently, have all finished running).

Any hints?

## Iteration 2: Spawning Tasks

Thanks always to Ryan Pierce Williams, I have modified the classes and now the only real problem is how to **cancel** a list of upcoming/current tasks.

The interface to the workload now creates a new instance of a Text-To-Speech class taken from Xamarin's tutorial (I still want to play it simple!), and is as follows:

```
public interface ITextToSpeech
{
    ITextToSpeech New(string text, CancellationTokenSource source, CancellationToken token);
    void Speak(string text);
    Task SpeakAsync(string text);
    void CancelSpeak();
}

public class TextToSpeechImplementation : ITextToSpeech
{
    public string speech_text;
    public AVSpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer;
    public AVSpeechUtterance speechUtterance;
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsUtterance;
    public CancellationTokenSource cancel_source;
    public CancellationToken cancel_token;

    public ITextToSpeech New(string text, CancellationTokenSource source, CancellationToken token)
    {
        speech_text = text;
        cancel_source = source;
        cancel_token = token;

        speechSynthesizer = new AVSpeechSynthesizer();
        speechUtterance = new AVSpeechUtterance(speech_text);
        speechSynthesizer.DidFinishSpeechUtterance += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("STOP IMPLEMENTATION {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        speechSynthesizer.DidCancelSpeechUtterance += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SPEECH CANCELED");

        return this;
    }

    public void Speak(string text)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("START IMPLEMENTATION {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        speechSynthesizer.SpeakUtterance(speechUtterance);
    }

    public async Task SpeakAsync(string text)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("START ASYNC IMPLEMENTATION {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        tcsUtterance = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        speechSynthesizer.SpeakUtterance(speechUtterance);
        await tcsUtterance.Task;
    }

    public void CancelSpeak()
    {
        speechSynthesizer.StopSpeaking(AVSpeechBoundary.Immediate);
        tcsUtterance?.TrySetResult(true);
        cancel_source.Cancel();
    }
}
```

And the widget class now uses **only synchronous calls** to the workload, as I am spawning tasks I don't think I need `async` there:

```
    public bool is_playing;
    public CancellationTokenSource cancel_source;
    public CancellationToken cancel_token;
    public List<string> l;

    public PlayerWidget(int category, int book)
    {
        is_playing = false;
        l = new List<string>();
        cancel_source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancel_token = cancel_source.Token;
    }

    public void Play_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!is_playing)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("start");

            is_playing = true;

            l.Clear();
            l.Add("Wait for five seconds...");
            l.Add("You waited!");
            l.Add("and the last one is here for you.");
            l.Add("Just kidding, my man, you have this last sentence here and shall be perfectly said. Now I have to go... so... farewell!");

            var state = new TaskState()
            {
                Delay = 1000,
                CancellationToken = cancel_token,
                Workload = DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().New(l[0], cancel_source, cancel_token)
            };

            Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskExecutor, state, cancel_token).ContinueWith(TaskComplete);
        }
        else
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("stop");
            is_playing = false;
            cancel_source.Cancel();
        }
    }

    public void TaskExecutor(object obj)
    {
        var state = (TaskState)obj;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Delaying execution of Task {0} for {1} [ms] at {2}", state.TaskId, state.Delay, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        state.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Delay execution, while monitoring for cancellation
        // If Task.Delay isn't responsive enough, use something like this.
        var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < state.Delay)
        {
            Thread.Yield(); // don't hog the CPU
            state.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Beginning to process workload of Task {0} '{1}' at {2}", state.TaskId, l[state.TaskId], System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        state.Workload.Speak(l[state.TaskId]);
    }

    void TaskComplete(Task parent)
    {
        var state = (TaskState)parent.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            parent.Wait();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Task {0} successfully completed processing its workload without error at {1}", state.TaskId, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("The Task {0} was successfully cancelled at {1}", parent.AsyncState, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

            // since it was cancelled, just return. No need to continue spawning new tasks.
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("An unexpected exception brought Task {0} down. {1} at {2}", state.TaskId, ex.Message, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        }

        if (state.TaskId == l.Count - 1)
        {
            is_playing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Kick off another task...
            var child_state = new TaskState()
            {
                Delay = 5000,
                CancellationToken = cancel_token,
                Workload = DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().New(l[state.TaskId + 1], cancel_source, cancel_token)
            };
            Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskExecutor, child_state, cancel_token).ContinueWith(TaskComplete);
        }
    }
```

Now it works like a charm, it schedules correctly, and the workloads get executed. Nice.

The problem now is: **how do I cancel tasks**? I need to **stop** the currently playing TTS, and prevent any other task to be created. The way I thought is that calling to `cancel_source.Cancel();` would be sufficient, but it isn't, as you see from the log:

```
start
Delaying execution of Task 0 for 1000 [ms] at 10:21:16
Beginning to process workload of Task 0 'Wait for five seconds...' at 10:21:17
START IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:17
Task 0 successfully completed processing its workload without error at 10:21:17
Delaying execution of Task 1 for 5000 [ms] at 10:21:17
2018-10-24 10:21:17.565591+0200 TestTasks.iOS[71015:16136232] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=71015
2018-10-24 10:21:17.565896+0200 TestTasks.iOS[71015:16136232] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: TestTasks.iOS[71015]/0#-1 LF=0
STOP IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:19
Beginning to process workload of Task 1 'You waited!' at 10:21:22
START IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:22
Task 1 successfully completed processing its workload without error at 10:21:22
Delaying execution of Task 2 for 5000 [ms] at 10:21:22
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
STOP IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:23
Beginning to process workload of Task 2 'and the last one is here for you.' at 10:21:27
START IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:27
Task 2 successfully completed processing its workload without error at 10:21:27
Delaying execution of Task 3 for 5000 [ms] at 10:21:27
stop
An unexpected exception brought Task 3 down. One or more errors occurred. at 10:21:27
STOP IMPLEMENTATION 10:21:29
start
An unexpected exception brought Task 4 down. One or more errors occurred. at 10:21:34
stop
start
An unexpected exception brought Task 6 down. One or more errors occurred. at 10:21:39
```

My simple and naive code actually **does not stop the currently playing text** immediately, it continues until finishing the TTS and stops all the other tasks from being spawned. But if I click again on the play button, the tasks won't start again, and as you can see I have weird (to me) errors about spawning new tasks.

Again, I am new to this, what can I do?

## Iteration 3: Single Task, Multiple Tokens

As usual, suggestions from Ryan were very helpful, and right now I have succeeded in writing a very basic task handler that almost works:

```
    public void Play_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        l.Clear();
        l.Add("Wait for five seconds...");
        l.Add("You waited!");
        l.Add("and the last one is here for you.");
        l.Add("Just kidding, my man, you have this last sentence here and shall be perfectly said. Now I have to go... so... farewell!");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("click handler playing {0}", is_playing);

        try
        {
            if (!is_playing)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("start");

                cancel_source = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cancel_token = cancel_source.Token;
                current_task = new Task(SingleTask, cancel_token);
                current_task.Start();
                is_playing = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("stop");

                is_playing = false;
                cancel_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                cancel_source.Cancel();
                cancel_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
                cancel_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("cancel");

            cancel_source.Cancel();
            current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
            is_playing = false;
        }
    }
```

With the handler defined as follows:

```
    public void SingleTask()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task started at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        foreach(var p in l)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Waiting 5s");

            //cancel_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < 5000)
            {
                Thread.Yield(); // don't hog the CPU
                //cancel_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }

            current_speaker = DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().New(p, cancel_source, cancel_token);

            try
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task speaking at {0} sentence '{1}'", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), p);

                current_speaker.Speak(p);

                while (current_speaker.IsPlaying())
                {
                    Thread.Yield();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task CANCELING at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

                cancel_source.Cancel();
                current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task FINISHED at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        is_playing = false;
    }
```

Now the task get scheduled, executed, and works for multiple times. The problem is now **canceling** it.

**What works**: killing the task when TTS is speaking mid-sentence. It calls weirdly both "stop" and "cancel", but it works:

```
click handler playing True
stop
cancel
2018-10-29 12:35:37.534358+0100[85164:17740514] [AXTTSCommon] _BeginSpeaking: couldn't begin playback
SPEECH CANCELED
```

**What does not work**: killing the task when waiting for the next phrase. In the waiting period it calls again "stop" and "cancel", but as you can see it keeps going on with the **next** sentence, then it stops as I intended (it correctly begins again when clicking the button again).

```
click handler playing False
start
Single task started at 12:36:56
Waiting 5s
Single task speaking at 12:37:01 sentence 'Wait for five seconds...'
START IMPLEMENTATION 12:37:01
STOP IMPLEMENTATION 12:37:02
Waiting 5s
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #34
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #37
click handler playing True
stop
cancel
Single task speaking at 12:37:07 sentence 'You waited!'
START IMPLEMENTATION 12:37:07
STOP IMPLEMENTATION 12:37:08
```

I do believe that I am missing a very tiny piece here!

## Final Solution

This is the final code with Ryan's suggestions, it works now, it stops speeches mid-sentence, stops tasks when waiting, all I needed. For the posterity, the tricky part is having a task and native tasks mixed here (the TTS dependency service), but now I think it is cleaner and clearer:

```
    public void Play_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        l.Clear();
        l.Add("Wait for five seconds...");
        l.Add("You waited!");
        l.Add("and the last one is here for you.");
        l.Add("Just kidding, my man, you have this last sentence here and shall be perfectly said. Now I have to go... so... farewell!");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("click handler playing {0}", is_playing);

        if (!is_playing)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("start");

            cancel_source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cancel_token = cancel_source.Token;
            current_task = new Task(SingleTask, cancel_token);
            current_task.Start();
            is_playing = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("stop");

            is_playing = false;
            cancel_source.Cancel();
            current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
        }
    }

    public void SingleTask()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task started at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        foreach(var p in l)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Waiting 5s");

            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            while (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < 5000)
            {
                Thread.Yield(); // don't hog the CPU

                if (cancel_source.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    cancel_source.Cancel();
                    current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
                    return;
                }
            }

            current_speaker = DependencyService.Get<ITextToSpeech>().New(p, cancel_source, cancel_token);

            try
            { 
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task speaking at {0} sentence '{1}'", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), p);

                current_speaker.Speak(p);

                while (current_speaker.IsPlaying())
                {
                    Thread.Yield();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task CANCELING at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

                cancel_source.Cancel();
                current_speaker.CancelSpeak();
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Single task FINISHED at {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        is_playing = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hey @senseiwa, when you resume you atetmpt to resume your tasks after cancelling, you will need a new CancellationTokenSource (the old one was already cancelled and so any future tasks built with it will automatically cancel).

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams Thanks, I am close now! I have edited the code according to your suggestions and now it *almost* works. It spawns a task, speaks, and cancels mid-sentence, restarting if I click again. The only part that won't work is when it waits for the next sentence. Any hints are, as usual, very welcome, you're making me understand **a truckload** of Tasks/Threads! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it's helping :) As for your remaining issue, I've taken a look at your updated code and the thing that immediately pops out to me is that you are performing the checks against the cancellation token in the wrong location. Those checks should go in the task thread, not in your UI thread. The UI thread should tell the CancellationTokenSource instance to cancel, while the task should be checking the supplied CancellationToken retrieved from the CancellationTokenSource to see if a cancel has been requested.

Comment: Also, If you don't want an exception to be thrown in the task thread you can always alternatively use the IsCancellationRequested Property, which will just give you a boolean value.

Comment: It works @RyanPierceWilliams, thanks! I've edite the question, marked as solved, and if you see something fishy in my code don't hesitate to tell me. I thank you for the great help, it wasn't at all that easy to mix tasks, native tasks, and handling all the start/stop/cancel events. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. If there is one suggestion I would make to improve it: pass the cancellation token into the task as it's state parameter (or as a part of the state object). This practice will help make the code more re-usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET's Task Library, cancellation is treated as a request that the asynchronous task must respond to (exception: scheduled tasks that have not yet begun to run maybe cancelled by the framework if it detects that a cancellation has been requested).

In order for a task to check to see if a cancellation has been requested, you must pass along the CancellationToken to the task. This can be done as (or as part of) the optional state parameter. Below is an example of a task that will sit in an infinite loop until a cancellation is requested:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim cts As New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim ct = cts.Token
    Dim t = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf InfiniteLoop, ct, ct)

    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Console.WriteLine("Task Status after 5000 [ms]: {0}", t.Status)
    Debug.Assert(t.Status = TaskStatus.Running)

    cts.Cancel()
    Try
        t.Wait()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", ex.Message)
    End Try

    Console.WriteLine("Task Status after cancelling: {0}", t.Status)
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit....")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Public Sub InfiniteLoop(ByVal ct As CancellationToken)
    While True
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    End While
End Sub
```

As for doing tasks synchronously, just maintain a Work Queue (ConcurrentQueue). Use the Task.ContinueWith(...) with each task that you run so that it can go kick off the next item in the queue (or cancel them all).

You can use Task.Delay(5000) to kick off a task that will take 5 seconds to complete. Use Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith( myTask ) to delay execution of your tasks.

EDIT: The way you describe it, it sounds like you just want to continually generate new tasks until someone tells you to stop. I've written a sample application below that will do just that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskQueueExample
{
class Program
{
    public class TaskState
    {
        private static int _taskCounter = 0;

        public int TaskId { get; set;  }
        public int Delay { get; set; }
        public int Workload { get; set; }
        public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; set; }

        public TaskState()
        {
            TaskId = _taskCounter;
            _taskCounter++;
        }
    }

    static CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    static Random _rand = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var state = new TaskState() { Delay = _rand.Next(0, 1000), Workload= _rand.Next(0, 1000), CancellationToken = _cts.Token };

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Program.DoSomeWork, state, _cts.Token).ContinueWith(Program.OnWorkComplete);

        Console.WriteLine("Tasks will start running in the background. Press enter at any time to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    static void DoSomeWork(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        var state = (TaskState)obj;

        Console.WriteLine("Delaying execution of Task {0} for {1} [ms]", state.TaskId, state.Delay);

        state.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Delay execution, while monitoring for cancellation
        // If Task.Delay isn't responsive enough, use something like this.
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < state.Delay)
        {
            Thread.Yield(); // don't hog the CPU
            state.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Beginning to process workload of Task {0}", state.TaskId);

        // Simulate a workload (NOTE: no Thread.Yield())
        sw.Restart();
        while(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < state.Workload)
        {                
            state.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }           
    }

    static void OnWorkComplete(Task parent)
    {
        var state = (TaskState)parent.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            parent.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} successfully completed processing it's workload without error.", state.TaskId);
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Task {0} was successfully cancelled.", parent.AsyncState);

            // since it was cancelled, just return. No need to continue spawning new tasks.
            return;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An unexpected exception brought Task {0} down. {1}", state.TaskId, ex.Message);
        }

        // Kick off another task...
        var child_state = new TaskState() { Delay = _rand.Next(0, 1000), Workload = _rand.Next(0, 1000), CancellationToken = _cts.Token };
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Program.DoSomeWork, child_state, _cts.Token).ContinueWith(Program.OnWorkComplete);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, how about a **list** of tasks, a single task I can handle, but the proper way of handling several scheduled tasks with timer is a bit confusing right now to me.

Comment: A list of tasks is handled the same way. Pass a cancellation token to each task when you kick it off (all from the same CancellationTokenSource). Each task must then evaluate its cancellationToken periodically so that it can process the cancel request.

Comment: If you want immediate cancellation (instead of waiting for the Sleep/Delay to finish), use a tight loop that performs Yield until a certain amount of time has passed. Use a stopwatch timer to keep track of the time.

Comment: And don't use a Timer. As noted above, use a ConcurrentQueue to keep track of scheduled tasks. Use the Task.ContinueWith(...) to schedule the next task after the current completes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the question, since I am quite a newbie on .Net (as you probably guessed!) I still don't know how to make the `ContinueWith` work, it seems all the tasks start concurrently, or almost concurrently, so I have just one TTS and all the output lines in order, but immediately. I will deal with canceling next, as you can see now I have one token only as you suggested.

Comment: For clarification: do you start with a list of known tasks, or do you just want to continually generate tasks?

Comment: @senseiwa - I've added a sample application to my post that I think maybe what you are looking for. I've assumed you are wanting to generate a constant stream of tasks, rather than just working through a fixed list of tasks. It's about the same code either way - just pop from a queue of tasks instead of generating a new one if you only have a specific finite list of things to do.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, now scheduling works like a charm! But I don't know how to stop the current task and be able to restart it. I updated the question with your suggestions.

Comment: @senseiwa - There are different ways to approach that. Instead of generating a new TaskState each time you kick off a task, you could use a common TaskState that keeps track of where you are in the sequence of tasks. As long as you hold onto this TaskState then you can restart from wherever you left off based upon the data in TaskState. Hope this helps :)